# В буржуйском примере, вызов notification крушит приложение, но в новеньких Android все работает.

Tags: android, java

Вот сам пример [ссылка](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html)

Когда дело доходит до этой строчки, приложение вылетает.         
`notificationManager.notify(1234, noti.build());`

Причем судя по комментариям это касается только Androidов на подобии 2.2, для более новых Androidов этой ошибки либо не существует, либо она не критична.

1. Как исправить эту ситуацию для
       стареньких Androidов 2.2, чтоб и
       сообщения шли и приложение не
       вылетало?
2. Я же правильно понимаю, что эта
       строчка отвечает за вывод сообщения
       в тулбар?

### Попросили логи вот логи из LogCat

```
    09-06 17:01:16.108: I/LocationService(4303): onHandleIntent 55.1574875,61.3860029
09-06 17:01:16.118: W/dalvikvm(4303): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[Fused Location]
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=ru.chekaginsk.taxibro id=1234 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1251)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:110)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:90)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at ru.chekaginsk.taxibro.LocationService.onHandleIntent(LocationService.java:39)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-06 17:01:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(4303):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Вот логи из LogCat(depricated)

```
    09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[Fused Location]
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=ru.chekaginsk.taxibro id=1234 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1251)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:110)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:90)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at ru.chekaginsk.taxibro.LocationService.onHandleIntent(LocationService.java:39)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-06 17:01:10.258: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-06 17:01:10.268: WARN/ActivityManager(153):   Force finishing activity ru.chekaginsk.taxibro/.MyActivityTwo
```

Comment: @Gennady покажи логи краха

Comment: NotificationManager Added in API level 1 - должно на всех работать. Скорее всего проблема другого рода (возможно неправильно подключены [lay services)

Comment: @Barmaley добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К нотификации не добавлен `PendingIntent contentIntent` - то есть неизвестно какой будет запускаться `Intent` при нажатии на нотификацию. Логгер даже подсказывает пакет `ru.chekaginsk.taxibro` - так что **бро** пиши `PendingIntent` который кажет куда надо! :)